# How to rotate an image about the image center using homography?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am using opencv `warpPerspective` to generate images with different rotation to evaluate my feature point detection algorithm.

In homography matrix, the up-left 2x2 matrix is the rotation matrix, [as referred here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087241/opencv-warpperspective).

But the result is a rotation about the origin( the up-left corner), how can I modify the homography matrix to rotate the image about its center?

Regards.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html#warp-affine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this matrix

[image]

an affine transformation that translates and rotates, center is the center of rotation. To get a homography from this just need to add the last raw `[ 0 0 1]`. You can use [getRotationMatrix2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=getperspective#getrotationmatrix2d) to compute this matrix, and then either use `warpAffine` or form the homography and use `warpPerspective`. Please let us know how it goes.