# OpenCV,Warp images by Homography matrix

Tags: android, image, opencv, homography

I followed [Panorama – Image Stitching in OpenCV](http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/) to do same task on Android,by using `openCV4Android`.My problem is in about warping image by founded homography matrix.I tested these images:

image1:

[image]

image2:

[image]

Result of warping image1 by founded homography is:

[image]

You can see that result is good warped but **first part of that(left side) is cut!** So stitching result was:

[image]

And result of above images in referenced link page,is:

[image]

Why warping by homography cut that?Or may be I did some things wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! Finally I could solve the problem.I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8229116/1043882) and understand what causes this problem and how I can solve that:

> The problem occurs because the homography maps part of the image to
>   negative x,y values which are outside the image area so cannot be
>   plotted. what we wish to do is to offset the warped output by some
>   number of pixels to 'shunt' the entire warped image into positive
>   coordinates(and hence inside the image area)...So just premultiply
>   your homography by a matrix similar to the above, and your output
>   image will be offset.

Answer (score 1):

Image 1 does not have any information about the rest of the scene. Since you're only applying the homography on image 1, it gets warped with respect to image 2 but doesn't really add any further scene information.

To get the resultant image you need, check the furthest x and y shift of image 1 after warping, and add this missing region along with stitching image 2. This isn't as simple as an addition, because the resultant image is larger, but it isn't too complicated either.

Comment: I tried to follow what I linked at first and tested it's images.But why it's result is OK?

Comment: Not sure why you edited out your code... Anyway, if you compare your code and what you've linked, the part where the result image is initialised, and where warped image 1 and image 2 are copied to it, are completely different. Comparing these portions line by line will answer your question.