# What is the difference between warpPerspective and perspectiveTransform?

Tags: c++, opencv, transform

I have used four sets of points to get a perspective transform matrix. Then using `warpPerspective` to transform the matrix `A` to matrix `B`. Point a from Mat A. I want to get the new point a position in mat B. But `warpPerspective` cannot do that, while `perspectiveTransform` can.

Here I want to know if the position that `perspectiveTransform` gets is the same as the position in matrix B by using `warpPerspective`.

So, what is the difference between `warpPerspective` and `perspectiveTransform`?

```
Mat trans = getPerspectiveTransform(dst, gpsPoints);
warpPerspective(A, B, trans, image.size());
Point2f a = Point2f(..., ...);         //were known
vector<Point2f> obj(1);
obj[0] = a;
vector<Point2f> b; 
perspectiveTransform(obj, b, trans);//if the new point in B is c, is c equals to b?
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`warpPerspective` works for images. In other words, warpPerspective can warp image A and put the result in B using the H (Homography or warpMatrix) so it has the following struct:

```
void warpPerspective(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray M, Size dsize, int flags=INTER_LINEAR, int borderMode=BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar& borderValue=Scalar())
```

`src` is the `Mat` you want to warp, `dst` where the result will be stored.

`perspectiveTransform` works for set of points. It applies the H (Homography or warpMatrix) on set of points (which are in `vector` for example) and put the results in another `vector`. The results are the points in the first `vector` after applying the warping. it has the following struct:

```
void perspectiveTransform(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray m)
```

where `src` is the input points, `dst` is the results of warping the input points.

**Conclusion**:

**Mathematically**, they both do the same thing which is warping a set of point using H.

**Technically**, `warpPerspective` do this on the coordinates of the `Mat` and move the pixel value(color) to a new pixel. `perspectiveTransform`, it just compute the new coordinate of the point and store it in the new `vector`.

Comment: So.you mean that the result is same in my case ?